# Visual Studio - find out why Visual Studio tries to link to class X?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost

I am getting a boost Linker error in Visual Studio (2012) for a library which I am not using. I am trying to establish whether VS2012 thinks my code is using the particular library, or whether its complaining about all my boost linking paths and this just happens to be the first file it fails to link to.

Is there any way I can "ask" Visual Studio why it is trying to link to a certain library?

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
'libboost_date_time-iw-mt-gd-1_54.lib'
```

I am not using any boost date/time classes- but I wonder if forgetting to include "std::" at beginning makes compiler think I am using a similarly-named std.

Comment: Without the code that might be causing the issue... there is no way to know

Comment: @Mgetz I can't post the whole project- can I? Thats why I am asking how can I find which code is causing the linking??

Comment: You can post a [simple program that reproduces the issue](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Mgetz: that's not likely to help with toolchain issues.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19797690/332733 @MSalters actually knowing what headers they are including WOULD help, as boost auto includes libraries. However this is still a duplicate of the question above as this is an issue caused by using the Intel compiler with VS.

Comment: Good catch on Intel compiler; that wasn't shown here (so it was a toolchain issue, as suspected).